# LWC issue with array variable being blank when accessed from another function

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, javascript-controller, lwc-dom

I am building a custom file upload component as follows.  I prepare my list of uploaded files inside the function handleFilesUpload.  I then call another function called handleSaveFiles but inside of this function the variable that holds the list of files is empty.  Can someone point me to why that is please?

**docs.html**

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-m-around_medkium">
    <lightning-input type="file" 
    onchange={handleFilesUpload}
    multiple>
    </lightning-input>
  </div>
 <template if:true={showUpload}>
  <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01">
      <div>
          <button onclick={closePopUp}>x</button>
          <div>
              <h1>Select File Type</h1>
          </div>
          <div>
              <div>
                  <lightning-combobox name="File Type" label="File Type" value="" placeholder="Choose File Type" options={filetype}
                      onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
              </div>
          </div> 
      </div>
  </section>
  <div role="presentation"></div>
</template>
</template>
```

**docs.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getFiles from '@salesforce/apex/docsUpload.getFiles';
import saveFiles from '@salesforce/apex/docsUpload.saveFiles';

export default class docs extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId
    filesUploaded = [];
    showUpload = false;
    filetype = { id: 1, label: "Item 1" },
        { id: 2, label: "Item 2" },
        { id: 3, label: "Item 3" }
    ]
       
    connectedCallback() {
        this.loadFiles();
    }

    loadFiles() {
        getFiles({appId: this.recordId})
        .then(result => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }

    handleFilesUpload(event) {
        let files = event.target.files;
        let filescount = files.length;
        let readOpearationCount = 0;
        if(files.length > 0) {
            let filesName = '';
            for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                let file = files[i];
                filesName = filesName + file.name + ',';
                let freader = new FileReader();
                freader.onload = () => {
                    var fileContents = freader.result.split(',')[1]
                    this.filesUploaded.push({'fileName':file.name, 'fileContent':fileContents});
                };
                freader.onloadend = () => {
                    readOpearationCount++;
                    if(readOpearationCount == filescount) {
                        this.showUpload = true;
                        this.handleSaveFiles();
                    }
                };
                freader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }
    }

    handleSaveFiles() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.filesUploaded));
    
        saveFiles({
            recordId: this.recordId,
            fileData: JSON.stringify(this.filesUploaded)
        })
        .then(result => {
            if(result){
                this.filesUploaded = [];
                console.log('file uploaded successfully.');
            }
            else {
                console.log('error during file upload');
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`freader.onload` runs only when the read operation triggered by `readAsDataURL` (or `readAsText`) ends and only if the file has been read successfully. Since you call `this.handleSaveFiles()` right after the for-loop, it will always run before the first onload handler. That's why `filesUploaded` is empty.

You should call `this.handleSaveFiles()` only after every file has been read. To keep track of occured read, you could leverage [`loadend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/loadend_event) event since it's fired when a file read has completed, successfully or not, while `load` event is fired just when a file has been read successfully.

```js
handleFilesUpload(event) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    const filesCount = files.length;
    let readOperationCount = 0;
    for(const file of files) {
        const freader = new FileReader();
        freader.onload = () => {
            const fileContents = freader.result.split(',')[1]
            this.filesUploaded.push({'fileName': file.name, 'fileContent': fileContents});
        };
        freader.onloadend = () => {
            readOperationCount++;
            if (readOperationCount === filesCount) {
                // Call handleSaveFiles only when every file has been read
                this.handleSaveFiles();
            }
        };
        freader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Please note that [`readAsDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) reads file's data as a base64 encoded string, if you're reading text files (like csv or json) you could use [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) avoiding base64 encode/decode operations.

Comment: @RubenDB, thank you.  That fixed my issue.  If I may ask another question.  I have a custom picklist field on the ContentVersion table called Type.  The values for Type__c are: "Proof of Income", "Proof of Residency", etc.  When a file gets uploaded via the custom LWC I am building as above, how can I present a user with a list of values from the field Type so that they can tag the file as one of the types?

Comment: @degmo You're welcome, glad I could help. You could leverage either a lightning-input-field or a combobox and [`getPicklistValues`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-wire-adapters-picklist-values.html) wire adapter. Provide a default value and attach an handler for the change event, storing the selected value in an instance variable, then add it as input parameter to `saveFiles` method.

Comment: Hi @RubenDG
thank you again. I need a little more help if you could. I put a prototype based on your suggestion to allow for selection of a file type. I updated the HTML file to icnlude a "dialog" section that pops up when "showupload" is true. However, save operation goes on while the dialog is still open. how can I make SaveFiles wait until the dialog is closed? Much appreciated. This is my first LWC component so I do appreciate your help..my experience so far has been with backend development

Comment: @degmo If the user should select first the type, then upload the file, I would modify the html having first `<template lwc:if={showUpload}` (please note that `if:true` and `if:false` are deprecated, you should use `lwc:if|elseif|else` directive), then, after closing that template element, I would put the container of lightning-input: `<div class="slds-m-around_medium" lwc:else>`. In the modal I would add a button to confirm the selection of the file type. This button would toggle `showUpload`. Another way to achieve this is disable the lightning-input until the user choose a file type.

Comment: anyway comments are not meant for extended discussion. Moreover you should not change the original question. Therefore I think opening a new question would be the best. This way you could get advice from the whole community.